# Evaluation of $\int_{0}^{\pi}\log(2+\cos x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How can I evaluate the definite integral $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\log(2+\cos x)dx$$
without using integral with parameters? This question is not difficult , if we use the acknowledge of integral with parameters.Actually, I want find a series of skillful substitutions to deal with it concisely.

Applying the integral with parameters,my answer is $
\pi\log(1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$.

Comment: Why don't you wish to try the Feynman technique by introducing a parameter? I don't think the solution is possible by using some sort of elementary anti-derivative.

Comment: Please add details as to what techniques you have tried or what type of answer you are expecting. In this site, your question will most likely be answered if you provide your workings and experimentation.

Comment: Ok you may add in your question that you know the Feynman approach and seek alternative methods.

Comment: If this can help,$$I-\pi\log2=\int_0^\pi\log\left(1+\frac{\cos x}2\right)\,dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k\,2^{2k+1}}\int_0^\pi\cos^{2k}(x)\,dx
\\=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k\,2^{2k+1}}\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!}\pi.$$

Answer (score 8):

Here is to integrate with just substitutions. Let $a=2-\sqrt3$ and rewrite the integral as

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln(2+\cos x)dx=2\pi \ln\frac{1+\sqrt3}2 + \int_{0}^{\pi}\ln(1+a^2-2a\cos \gamma)d\gamma\tag 1
$$
Substitute $c^2= 1+a^2-2a\cos \gamma$ while recognizing that $c$, $a$ and $1$ represent the sides of a triangle with the angles $\gamma = \pi-\beta(\gamma) - \alpha (\gamma) $. Then

\begin{align}
& \frac12\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln(1+a^2-2a\cos \gamma)d\gamma 
= -\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln c(\gamma) \>( d\beta(\gamma)+ d\alpha(\gamma) )\\ 
= &-\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln \frac{1\cdot \sin\gamma}{\sin\beta(\gamma) }\>d\beta  -\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln \frac{a\sin\gamma}{\sin\alpha(\gamma) }\>d\alpha\\
= &
\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln \sin\gamma\>d\gamma +\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln \sin\beta(\gamma) \>\overset{ t= \beta(\gamma) }{d\beta(\gamma)}+ \int_{0}^{\pi}\ln \frac{\sin\alpha(\gamma) }a \>\overset{ s= \alpha(\gamma)} {d\alpha(\gamma)}\\
= &\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln \sin\gamma\>d\gamma +\int_{\pi}^{0}\ln \sin tdt+ \int_{0}^{0}\ln \frac{\sin s}ads =0 \\
\end{align}

Thus, the integral (1) is
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln(2+\cos x)dx=2\pi \ln\frac{1+\sqrt3}2 $$

Comment: This was a very smart use of properties of triangles. +1

Answer (score 8):

**In General**

For $|\alpha|\lt1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\log\left(1+\alpha^2+2\alpha\cos(\theta)\right)
&=\log\left(1+\alpha e^{i\theta}\right)+\log\left(1+\alpha e^{-i\theta}\right)\tag1\\[9pt]
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{\alpha^k}ke^{ik\theta}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{\alpha^k}ke^{-ik\theta}\tag2\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}2\frac{\alpha^k}k\cos(k\theta)\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $1+\alpha^2+2\alpha\cos(\theta)=\left(1+\alpha e^{i\theta}\right)\left(1+\alpha e^{-i\theta}\right)$
$(2)$: power series for $\log(1+x)$
$(3)$: $e^{ik\theta}+e^{-ik\theta}=2\cos(k\theta)$

Thus, integrating $(3)$ over $[0,\pi]$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\int_0^\pi\log\left(1+\alpha^2+2\alpha\cos(\theta)\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\tag4\\
&=\pi\log(2\alpha)+\int_0^\pi\log\left(\frac{1+\alpha^2}{2\alpha}+\cos(\theta)\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\tag5\\
&=\pi\log\left(\frac2{\beta+\sqrt{\beta^2-1}}\right)+\int_0^\pi\log\left(\beta+\cos(\theta)\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(4)$: $(3)$ and $\int_0^\pi\cos(k\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta=0$
$(5)$: pull $\pi\log(2\alpha)$ out of the integral
$(6)$: $\alpha=\frac1{\beta+\sqrt{\beta^2-1}}$ is the root of $\frac{1+\alpha^2}{2\alpha}=\beta$ with $|\alpha|\lt1$

Therefore,
$$
\int_0^\pi\log\left(\beta+\cos(\theta)\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta
=\pi\log\left(\frac{\beta+\sqrt{\beta^2-1}}2\right)\tag7
$$
Substitute $\beta\mapsto\frac\beta\gamma$ and add $\pi\log(\gamma)$:
$$
\int_0^\pi\log\left(\beta+\gamma\cos(\theta)\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta
=\pi\log\left(\frac{\beta+\sqrt{\beta^2-\gamma^2}}2\right)\tag8
$$

---

**Applied to this problem**
$$
\int_0^\pi\log(2+\cos(x))\,\mathrm{d}x=\pi\log\left(\frac{2+\sqrt3}2\right)\tag9
$$