# Calculate $\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln(x+y \cos(t)) ~dt$

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

I'm working on a close form for
$$f(x, y) = \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln\left(x+y \cos(t)\right) \text{d} t$$

I've yet to find the entire domain of existence for $f$, however by differenciating under the integral sign, I get the following equation :
$$y \frac{\partial f} {\partial y}+x \frac{\partial f} {\partial x} = \pi$$

However this gives $$f(x, y) = \pi \ln(x) - \pi \ln(2) \cdot \frac{y}{x} $$ with the condition $f(x, x) = \pi \ln(x/2)$ which does not seem to fit numerically. I've also found

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(x, y\right) = \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\text{d} t}{x+y\cos(t)} =\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}$$

But I find it tricky to integrate because it gives an expression that doesn't seem to exist when $y$ tends towards $x$. Can someone point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: @TedShifrin Hi, sorry but I don't understand my mistakes on the PDE, can you explain me? It seems like if I plug it in, I obtained the integral of dt from 0 to pi. I must do something wrong somewhere...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the PDE. How did you get $f(x, y) = \pi \ln(x) - \pi \ln(2) * \frac{y}{x}
$?

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $x>|y|>0$ for the integral to exist. Note that
$$x+y \cos t = a(1+2r\cos t+r^2)$$
with $a= \frac12\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-y^2}\right) $, $r= \frac xy -\sqrt{\frac {x^2}{y^2}-1}$, and

\begin{align} 
&\int_0^{\pi}\ln( 1 + 2r\cos t + r^2) dt
 =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-r)^{k+1}}k  \int_0^{\pi}\cos kt\ dx =0
\end{align}

Thus
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln(x+y \cos t)dt=\int_0^\pi \ln a \ dt=  \pi \ln\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}2
$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $x>0$, $-x \le y \le x$ and

$$
I(y) := \int_0^{\pi} \log\left(x+y\cos(t)\right)\text{d}t.
$$

Therefore:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I'(y)
& = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{\cos(t)}{x+y\cos(t)}\text{d}t \\
& = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{y}\text{d}t - \frac{x}{y} \int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{x+y\cos(t)}\text{d}t \\
& = \frac{\pi}{y} - \frac{x}{y}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x+y\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}}\frac{2}{1+u^2}\text{d}u \\
& = \frac{\pi}{y} - \frac{2x}{y(x+y)} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+\frac{x-y}{x+y}u^2}\text{d}u \\
& = \frac{\pi}{y} - \frac{2x}{y\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}\lim_{b \to \infty} \int_0^b \frac{\sqrt{\frac{x-y}{x+y}}}{1+\left(\sqrt{\frac{x-y}{x+y}}u\right)^2}\text{d}u \\
& = \frac{\pi}{y} - \frac{2x}{y\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}\lim_{b \to \infty} \left[\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{x-y}{x+y}}b\right)-\arctan(0)\right] \\
& = \frac{\pi}{y} - \frac{\pi x}{y\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}. \\
\end{aligned}
$$

On the other hand:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I(y)
& = \int \frac{\pi}{y}\text{d}y - \int \frac{\pi x}{y\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}\text{d}y \\
& = \int \frac{\pi}{y}\text{d}y - \int \frac{\pi}{\sin(u)}\text{d}u \\
& = \int \frac{\pi}{y}\text{d}y - \int \frac{\pi}{v}\text{d}v \\
& = \pi\log\left|\frac{y}{v}\right| + c \\
& = \pi\log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-y^2}\right) + c \\
\end{aligned}
$$

and:

$$
I(0) = \pi\log(x) = \pi\left(\log(2)+\log(x)\right) + c
\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad
c = -\pi\log(2)
$$

from which:

$$
I(y) = \pi\log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-y^2}\right) - \pi\log(2)
$$

i.e.

$$
\boxed{\int_0^{\pi} \log\left(x+y\cos(t)\right)\text{d}t = 2\pi\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+y}+\sqrt{x-y}}{2}\right)}.
$$

Comment: Hi, if I follow your answer, I find the same $\partial f / \partial y$ as me, which satisfies the PDE I wrote that seems wrong, do you see why?

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln\left(x+y \cos t\right) dt=\int_0^\pi \ln y dt+\int_0^\pi \ln(\beta+\cos t)dt, ~~~~\beta=\frac{x}y$$

Use [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3683351/evaluation-of-int-0-pi-log2-cos-xdx?rq=1):

> $$
> \int_0^\pi\log\left(\beta+\cos(\theta)\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta
> =\pi\log\left(\frac{\beta+\sqrt{\beta^2-1}}2\right)\tag7
> $$

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln\left(x+y \cos t\right) dt=\pi \ln y+\pi\ln\left(\frac{\beta+\sqrt{\beta^2-1}}2\right)=\pi\ln\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}2\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to follow the steps for your PDE, but I can at least provide an over-the-top alternative.

Note that the integral converges for $0 <|y| < x$. Using $\displaystyle \ln\left(1+f(x\right))=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f(x)}{1+tf(x)}dt$ and Fubini's Theorem, we have

$$
\begin{align}
I &:= \int_{0}^{\pi}\ln\left(x+y\cos t\right)dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi}\ln xdt+\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln\left(1+\frac{y}{x}\cos t\right)dt \\
&= \pi\ln x+\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\frac{y}{x}\cos t}{1+\frac{uy}{x}\cos t}dudt \\
&= \pi\ln x+\frac{y}{x}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos t}{1+\frac{uy}{x}\cos t}dtdu \\
&= \pi\ln x+\frac{y}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos t}{x+uy\cos t}dtdu \\
&= \pi\ln x+\frac{y}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{2it}+1}{2x+uy\left(e^{2it}+1\right)}dtdu. \\
\end{align}
$$

Parameterize $z = e^{it}$ on the unit circle $C$ centered at the origin, going counterclockwise with a radius of $1$. Then $I$ becomes

$$\pi\ln x+\frac{y}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\oint_{C}^{}\frac{1+z^{2}}{2xz+uy\left(1+z^{2}\right)}\frac{dz}{iz}du = \pi\ln x+\frac{y}{2i}\int_{0}^{1}\oint_{C}^{}\frac{1+z^{2}}{2xz^{2}+uyz\left(1+z^{2}\right)}dzdu.$$

The simple poles of the integrand are $z_0 :=0$, $z_1 := \displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-y^{2}u^{2}}-x}{uy}$, and $z_2 := \displaystyle \frac{-\sqrt{x^{2}-y^{2}u^{2}}-x}{uy}.$ Notice that $z_0$ and $z_1$ are always inside $C$ but not $z_2$. Using the residues at the simple poles, the double integral becomes

$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 2\pi i \left(\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1+z^{2}}{2xz^{2}+uyz\left(1+z^{2}\right)}, z = z_1\right) + \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1+z^{2}}{2xz^{2}+uyz\left(1+z^{2}\right)}, z = z_2\right)\right)du \\
=& \int_0^1 2\pi i \left( \lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0) \cdot \frac{1+z^{2}}{2xz^{2}+uyz\left(1+z^{2}\right)} + \lim_{z \to z_1} (z-z_1) \cdot \frac{1+z^{2}}{2xz^{2}+uyz\left(1+z^{2}\right)}\right)du. \\
\end{align}
$$

We proceed as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
I &= \pi\ln x+\pi y\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{uy}-\frac{x}{uy\sqrt{x^{2}-u^{2}y^{2}}}\right)du \\
&= \pi\ln x+\pi\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-y^{2}u^{2}}-x}{u\sqrt{x^{2}-y^{2}u^{2}}}du \\
&= \pi\ln x-\pi\int_{x}^{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}\frac{v-x}{\sqrt{x^{2}-v^{2}}\frac{v}{y}}\frac{v}{y\sqrt{x^{2}-v^{2}}}dv \\
&= \pi\ln x+\pi\int_{x}^{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}\frac{dv}{x+v} \\
&= \pi\ln x\ +\ \pi\Big[\ln\left(x+v\right)\Big]_{x}^{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}} \\
&= \pi\ln\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{x^{2}-y^{2}}}{2}\right). \\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

By my [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4470820/732917), we have
$$
\int_0^\pi \ln (x+y \cos t) d t 
= \pi \ln \left(\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}{2}\right)
$$